# Latest version of Glide giving dependency error

Tags: android, gradle, android-glide

I have upgraded the version of Glide from 4.0.0-RC0 to 4.4.0. But it is giving me an error saying

```
Error:Module 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
```

It is not saying which jar or any other information.
Does anybody know how to fix this? I am also attaching the entries for Glide in my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.4.0'
```

EDIT :  I am using the support library version 27.0.1

Comment: You have put the annotationyProcessor lines 2 times

Comment: Thats a typo while asking the question, it is not there in my code. Editing the question now.

Comment: The issue is with Glide ,https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2318  , try 4.3.1 version i did not had any issue with that

Comment: @Redman I was able to fix the dependency error but now the app crashes with the following error: 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/bumptech/glide/gifdecoder/GifDecoder$BitmapProvider;

I need to use the most updated version of Glide to support some complex animations in my app, that'swhy I am trying to make this thing work.

Comment: Have you tried importing Glide with `compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}`

Comment: I did, thats how I fixed the dependency error but after that the app started to crash.

Comment: @Ezio, can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @MatPag this is the error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/bumptech/glide/gifdecoder/GifDecoder$BitmapProvider

Comment: @Ezio are you using multidex? if yes which version?

Comment: @MatPag we do use multidex, its 1.0.0

Comment: @Ezio I've found  a Glide issue with your same problem. The user solved using multidex 1.0.1 https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2633. You could try and check if it changes something (supposing you have correctly configured multidexing)

Comment: I already tried this, this user was facing the issue in version 4.3.1, which is working fine in my app without any change in multidex. I am facing this problem in version 4.4.0. I guess I will use 4.3.1 and see how it goes.

Comment: You should create a detailed issue in the glide github project and wait for answers from project mantainers (Google engineers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue, but using this solved it :

```
compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

To pull in the annotations module which contains @GlideModule, you have to use `transitive = true`

Comment: works for 4.4.0 but not 4.6.0.  I will revert back to 4.4.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is may be glide issue so, I will prefer to don't update glide to `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0` till now. you can use older version like `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1` or `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0` or `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0`

you can read more about these issues on

[issue 2318](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2318)

[issue 2319](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/pull/2319)

Answer (score 1):

Just use this in app.gradle and you are done :

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to do these steps to avoid this error:

1 - update your sdk version to 27

2 - In your dependencies in build.gradle:

```
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

And you are good to go as this one resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

Once check with this dependencies for latest android studio 3.0.2 this dependencies build proper gradle.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this in your build. Simply:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer. it is the same thing that I have, "implementation" is introduced in latest gradle version. I dont have any issues with my gradle version.